# WPF DataTemplate in Code Behind crashes when setting width property

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have following Code:

```
protected override DataTemplate _CreateDataTemplate()
{
    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DockPanel));
    factory.SetBinding(Panel.BackgroundProperty, new Binding(CellContentBindingPath.Replace(".ValueUser", ".Background")));
    dataTemplate.VisualTree = factory;
    var childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
    childFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, 15);
    factory.AppendChild(childFactory);

    childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    factory.AppendChild(new FrameworkElementFactory(""));
    childFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, !ShowZero ? new Binding(CellContentBindingPath) { Converter = new ValueToNothingConverter() } : new Binding(CellContentBindingPath));
    childFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, ContentAlignment);            
    factory.AppendChild(childFactory);

    return dataTemplate;
}
```

The Error is "15 is not a valid value for property width".

When I don't set the width of the image everything works fine. Unfortunately the width is pretty important.

Sorry for the bad code formatting, I didn't found out how to make it well formatted.

Comment: "Crashes"? What exception is thrown?

Comment: 15 is not a valid value for property width

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`FrameworkElement.Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is of type [*double*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), but you're trying to set it to an *integer* value.

Instead, write it like one of the following:

```
childFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, 15.0);
childFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, 15d);
childFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, 15D);
```

Comment: @HansDabi I added more examples for you. Please take a look into the link to the MSDN "double" page.

Comment: if it solves your issue it should get up voted at least.